# Bazel build Tensorflow Serving fails in Mac

Tags: macos, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I've a Mac which runs Sierra. I installed all pre-requisites for tensorflow serving as mentioned here.

https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/setup

But when I try to bazel build tensorflow serving as they mentioned, I get 3 errors and the build stops.

```
error use of undeclared identifier 'pthread_mach_thread_np'
```

Answer (score 1):

Inserting following lines of code

```
#ifndef _MACH_PORT_T
#define _MACH_PORT_T
#include <sys/_types.h> /* __darwin_mach_port_t */
typedef __darwin_mach_port_t mach_port_t;
#include <pthread.h>
mach_port_t pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_t);
#endif /* _MACH_PORT_T */
```

into file:

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__threading_support

This issue is discussed [in this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13220).